# Reflect changes of the Maven coordinates on mvnrepository.com

Tags: maven

A while ago, I changed the `artifactId` of one of my open source libraries (the reason was a rename of the project).

I saw that `mvnrepository.com` can link to the new artifact in such cases:
[image]

I could not, however, find any documentation about this. Is this a Maven feature or a feature of `mvnrepository.com` and how does it work? Is this maintained by hand or can I add some configuration in my `pom.xml` to trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is based on the Maven feature "relocation"

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html

which allows you to add a relocation target like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <relocation>
    <groupId>some.id</groupId>
  </relocation>
</distributionManagement>
```